# Android: using the same service in several activities

Tags: android, service

Is it common for several activities to use/share the same service? If so, what is the best way to do this? Does each activity need to bind to that service (i.e. each activity has its own ServiceConnection object)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it common for several activities to use/share the same service?

Yes, you can bind service from different activities. It's basically one of the reasons services were introduced.

> Does each activity need to bind to that service?

Yes, you should treat each activity as independent part and that's why each activity should create it's own connection.